# Column extract a variable from data frame

Tags: r

simple question ahoy:

I have a data frame with three columns: a,b,c. How would I extract a specific column from a variable? For example:

```
test <- data.frame(3,4,5)
column = "X4"
```

If I try

```
test$column
```

I get `NULL`. If I try

```
test$X4
```

I get the right answer of `4`. What am I missing about the test$column bit that isn't working the way I want it to? Thanks!

Comment: try `test[[column]]` (another option is `test[,column]`)

Comment: Look a the `$` section. http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html